# Using "quién" and "quiénes" properly

Tags: gramática

Am I using *quién* and *quiénes* properly?

If I think that there is **someone** here, I would say

```
¿Quién está aquí?
```

If I think that there are **people** here but do not know how many, I would say

```
¿Quién está aquí?
```

If I think that there are **five people** here, I would say

```
¿Quiénes están aquí?
```

If I am having a conversation with a friend and is expecting a **singular answer**, I would say

```
¿Quién come cebolla?
```

If I am having a conversation with a friend and is expecting a **plural answer**, I would say

```
¿Quiénes comen cebolla?
```

If I am having a conversation with a friend and do not know if the answer would be **singular or plural**, I would say

```
¿Quién come cebolla?
```

If I am having a conversation with a friend and asked a **rhetorical question**, I would say

```
¿Quién come cebolla?
```

Comment: When you want to ask "who" , you can always use the "Quién" as a singular and expect a plural answer, and it should be most of the time the proper way of asking, after all, you don't know how many actually did it, even when you know it was more than one, you can keep saying it in singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrong in your examples. However, you are being too cautious. *Quién* is generic, meaning it's OK whether you think the answer can be singular or plural, **unless** you already are talking about several people. For example, this is one case when you should use *quiénes*:

> *—Esta noche vienen a cenar algunos amigos.*
>   *—¿Quiénes?*

Even in this case there are people that would use singular *¿quién?*. If you're in a group and you're all having dinner, for example, you might ask:

> *—¿Quién quiere postre?*

even though it's quite likely that **several** in the group will want to have dessert.

Conversely, *quiénes* is generic if you don't have any reason to suppose that the answer will be singular, for example:

> *—¿Quiénes vendrán esta noche a cenar?*
>   *—Sólo mi amigo Juan.*

As before, you cannot use *quiénes* if you've just established the conversation is about only one person:

> *—Hay una persona esperándote en la sala.*
>   *—¿Quién?*

So there are a few occasions when you should choose one or the other, but for the most part *quién* and *quiénes* are both OK, with each one providing a hint as to what you think the answer will be, but not changing the basic meaning.